# Node voltage - I am having trouble making my system of equations

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, homework

For the problem, I need to find the voltage of the two nodes on top.  I am using the node at the bottom as the reference node.

When trying to make my KCL equations I came up with:

v1/60 + v1/15 + (v1-v2)/5 - 15 = 0

and

v2/2 + (v2-v1)/5 - 5 = 0

Thiis is clearly incorrect because I can see the right answers when I check, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use nodal analysis you need a reference point (ground). You are free to place this reference voltage as you like. Where would a good place be for this reference do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You did an excellent job, except for an incorrect sign in just one place.

Let me teach you a different approach that will help you avoid such mistakes.

But beforehand, let me redraw the schematic so that the KCL is slightly easier to see:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSjvBw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's a good idea to get into the practice of redrawing schematics. In this case, it also labels the resistors and current source/sinks for you, too. And it makes clear which node is \$v_1\$ and which node is \$v_2\$ by writing them out, explicitly.

Now we are ready for a simpler approach to KCL. (See Appendix below.) Note that ground is treated as an arbitrarily assigned \$0\:\text{V}\$.

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rccc}
  {\text{KCL for node }v_1:}\vphantom{\frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_1}{R_2}+\frac{v_1}{R_3}}\\\\
  {\text{KCL for node }v_2:}\vphantom{\frac{v_2}{R_3}+\frac{v_2}{R_4}+i_2}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
     \frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_1}{R_2}+\frac{v_1}{R_3}\\\\
     \frac{v_2}{R_3}+\frac{v_2}{R_4}+i_2
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_1}{R_2}+\frac{v_1}{R_3}}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{v_2}{R_3}+\frac{v_2}{R_4}+i_2}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      \frac{v_2}{R_3}+i_1\\\\
      \frac{v_1}{R_3}
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

In the above, note that it's really easy to figure out where/how to place the current sources and sinks. The \$i_1\$ current is "inflowing" to \$v_1\$ and so it goes on the right.  The \$i_2\$ current is "outflowing" from \$v_2\$ and so it goes on the left. This keeps you thinking clearly and not worrying about signs (all signs are positive -- you are just moving things into the correct column, instead.)

Finally, I could have just as well written this out more fully as:

$$\begin{align*}
  \begin{array}{rccc}
  {\text{KCL for node }v_1:}\vphantom{\frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_1}{R_2}+\frac{v_1}{R_3}}\\\\
  {\text{KCL for node }v_2:}\vphantom{\frac{v_2}{R_3}+\frac{v_2}{R_4}+i_2}
  \end{array}
&&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{r}
     \frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_1}{R_2}+\frac{v_1}{R_3}\\\\
     \frac{v_2}{R_3}+\frac{v_2}{R_4}+i_2
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{outflowing currents}}
&
  \begin{array}{c}
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{v_1}{R_1}+\frac{v_1}{R_2}+\frac{v_1}{R_3}}\\\\
  &\quad{=}\vphantom{\frac{v_2}{R_3}+\frac{v_2}{R_4}+i_2}
  \end{array}
&
\overbrace{
 \begin{array}{l}
      \frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_1}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_2}+\frac{v_2}{R_3}+i_1\\\\
      \frac{v_1}{R_3}+\frac{0\:\text{V}}{R_4}
 \end{array}
  }^{\text{inflowing currents}}
\end{align*}$$

That shows all of the inflowing and outflowing elements written out, explicitly.

But as you can see, the zero values in the numerator can be left unstated as they don't contribute anything.

There's nothing to stop you from re-arranging any of the above KCL statements in order to achieve the form you want. All that the above does is help avoid sign errors as you don't have to figure out which is subtracted from which, anymore. All you do is assign things as "spilling out from the node" or "spilling into the node," so to speak.

### KCL Addendum

The KCL equations show outflowing currents on the left and inflowing currents on the right. This approach is used by some Spice programs (those where I've directly looked over the code used to generate these) to develop their KCL.

Perhaps the easiest way to imagine is that a voltage at a node ***spills away*** from that node ***through*** the available paths. But also that voltages ***spill back into*** that same node from surrounding nodes through those same paths. The result is the application of a simple superposition concept that results in, effectively, the potential differences controlling the result.

You can test this, easily, by rearranging the resulting equation(s), moving the right side over to the left side and then combining terms. You'll then see the usual potential differences that you expect. So it really is the same result.

The reason I very much prefer this method is that it is simple to visualize and very difficult to make mistakes. You can easily orient yourself to a node and then work out the terms for out-flowing currents for the left side of the equation. Then all you have to do is position yourself at each surrounding node and work out the terms for in-flowing currents for the right side. It's almost impossible to screw that up.

Conversely, when you are instead struggling to work out the potential differences in your mind (using the more traditionally taught method) and just write those terms, you often find yourself not entirely sure if you have the sign right as you try and add them up. I find, time and time again that not only others wind up messing up somewhere and making an uncaught mistake.. but that I also make those mistakes, as well. Even with lots of experience, you just aren't 100% sure and you often find yourself double and triple checking your work, just in case.

This approach also just works and works right without the continual question about orientations of signing expressions. With this method, I still make typos. But I don't make sign errors. It's too easy to use.

So voltage spills away from a node via available paths and voltage spills into a node from nearby nodes via the same available paths. The only caveat is that a current source or sink can only flow in, or flow out, but not both directions. It's one way. So it will either appear on the out-flowing side or on the in-flowing side -- but not both sides.

This also works perfectly well with capacitors and inductors. It does turn the equation into a differential/integral equation. But that's just a technicality. It's still correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your equations are summing the current **out** of each node. Take a look again at how you handled the two ideal current sources, and note the direction of each current.

Comment: does the - (current source) not satisfy for current coming in? as well as the v1-v2 and v2-v1, since I dont know which voltage is higher, I do not know which way the current is going.
How do I figure out how much current is coming in if it is.
(I was using + terms for current out and - terms for current in)

Comment: All you need to do is look at the direction of the arrows in the body of the current source symbol. You handled the resistors correctly, it is just the two ideal current sources that you need to reconsider....one of them is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

@ashiningjewel Your first equation is correct. Your second equation, however, is not right as you should be consistent about the signs.
It should be
$$\frac{V_2}{2}-\frac{V_{1}-V_{2}}{5}+5=0$$.
Be consistent about which convention you use; is it the leaving or the entering currents that are taken to be positive.